# Python Selenium Chrome Driver not typing the url after starting browser

Tags: python, selenium

I am doing a python selenium project , I am able to open the chrome browser but it is not typing url into it. Have below is my code and system details.

Python 2.7
Selenium 3.13
Chrome Driver 2.4
Chrome Version 67
Windows 10 -64 bit

Error : -Traceback (most recent call last)

Code :-

```
from selenium import webdriver

options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\User\aditi\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chrome driver\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Error Message

```
C:\Python27\python.exe     
"C:/Users/aditi/PycharmProjects/DMS/PolicyDownload.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aditi/PycharmProjects/DMS/PolicyDownload.py", line 5, in <module>
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chrome driver\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 251, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Comment: You didn't put error trackback here!

Comment: you should escape `\\` symbols in your argument or use raw strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Comment: As above, make sure your directory and the `user_data` file actually exists and you're specifying it correctly. As for the unknown error, seems it's been encountered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-d).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue resolved by replacing "\" which is 1 time , by 2 times backword slash"\"

Check if same work for you as well.